# foreach loop to print key value pairs while imploding the nested arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, implode

I'm trying to print all of the key value pairs we are getting from a form with a foreach loop. The problem is for the $values that are nested arrays, it is only printing array.

I would like this value to be flattened while maintaining the key. I've been trying an implode(', ', $value); in the loop. Is there a way to do this?

My current code is

```
foreach($cleanedArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value <br>";
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
company_name: asldjfklka 
contact_name: lkdasjf;l 
contact_phone: 39085034985 
contact_email: caosdfj@gmal.com 

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/certification-questionnaire-4.0/php/formshow.php on line 105
company_type: Array 
campaign: no
```

I've been trying an if statement within the foreach loop without luck.

```
    foreach($cleanedArray as $key => $value) {
  if (is_array($value)){
     implode(', ', $value);
  } 
    echo "$key: $value <br>";
}
```

The output that I'm looking for is this:

```
  company_name: asldjfklka 
  contact_name: lkdasjf;l 
  contact_phone: 39085034985 
  contact_email: caosdfj@gmal.com 
  company_type: retail, ecommerce, brickmorter
  campaign: no
```

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the structure of the nested array? does it have a definite structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of array you need to assign the result of `implode` to a variable:

```
foreach($cleanedArray as $key => $value) {
  if (is_array($value)){
     // here
     $value = implode(', ', $value);
  } 
  echo "$key: $value <br>";
}
```

Comment: Also of note @CFlynn9, if your nested array goes more than one level deep, you will run into the same problem as this accounts for one level. It sounds like this solution is sufficient for your needs, but if not you may need to make a recursive function to output values regardless of depth (although much trickier).

Comment: @u_mulder thanks assigning the implode() to the value variable worked like a charm